# Roast Turkey - rinse or not?

Tags: food-safety, turkey

I usually use the roasting bag for the turkey.  I always rinse & pat dry before baking, but I read a recipe in a grocery store magazine that said *not* to rinse it; just pat it dry.  Seems to go against safety practices.

Thoughts?

Comment: By the way, my secret tip is to put the turkey neck and a quartered lemon in the cavity!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rinsing is not necessary.  In fact, from a safety perspective, it is more risky to rinse poultry, because you present the opportunity to splatter and cross contaminate other items in your kitchen.  So, best not to rinse.  Just pat dry and proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the consensus is that rinsing poultry increase the chance of contamination by water droplets.